# JQuery Get JSON from servlet

Tags: jquery, html, json, servlets

I want to create a progressbar that takes data from the server (servlet).
So i create a html file and a servlet wich create json data(static for test purpose)

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("GetProgressEvent", function(data) {     
    $.each(data.ProgressEvents, function(){
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: this.progress });
     $("#progressStatus").html(this.status);
    });
    // setTimeout(arguments.callee, 500);
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

<div id="progressbar"></div>
<div id ="progressStatus"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet GetProgressEvent.java:

```
 @Override
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
      throws ServletException, IOException
   {
      resp.setContentType("application/json");
      resp.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
      PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
      out.println("{'ProgressEvents':[{'progress':"
         + 10
         + ",'status':'10%'},{'progress':"
         + 20
         + ",'status':'20%'},{'progress':"
         + 30
         + ",'status':'30%'}}]}");
      out.close();

   }
```

with firebug I noticed that the servlet sends the data normally, the data sent lokk like this:

```
{'ProgressEvents':[{'progress':10,'status':'10%'},{'progress':20,'status':'20%'},{'progress':30,'status':'30%'}}]}
```

but the problem that the loop is never executed and i dont understand why.
I just started with jQuery and I need your help,any help is apreciated
thank you in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that ' is not valid json you need double quotes.

You can validate the json using http://jsonlint.com/